# Is it possible in C++14 to capture specific member variables by reference

Tags: c++, c++14

I know that you can capture `this` to get access to class member variables. But this approaches exposes all variables at once. I would like to have access to specific subset of member variables. If I want to call lambda in place of declaration what are the downsides of passing member variables by reference as arguments instead of capturing them.

**Update:**
Seems like the most common answer is to do

```cpp
[&var = this->member_var]() { /* use var */ }
```

Comment: `[a = this->a, b = std::ref(this->b)](){/*..*/}`?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `[&capture_variable_name = this->member_name]`